# How to create future that completes once tokio::process::Child has exited without closing stdin

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

How can I create a future that completes upon the termination of a `tokio::process::Child` without closing `stdin`. I know there is `try_wait` for testing if a process has terminated without closing `stdin`, but I want to have this behavior with future semantics.

I tried to prepare a MRE for this question where my code panics as a result of writing to `stdin` after calling `wait`, but what I observe does not match the behavior stated in the documentation for `tokio::process::Child`'s [wait method](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.0.1/tokio/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait). I would expect to see that the line `stdin.write_u8(24).await.unwrap();` crashes with a broken pipe since `stdin` should have been closed by `wait`.

```rust
use tokio::{time, io::AsyncWriteExt}; // 1.0.1

use std::time::Duration;

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let mut child = tokio::process::Command::new("nano")
        .stdin(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    
    let mut stdin = child.stdin.take().unwrap();

    let tasklet = tokio::spawn(async move {
        child.wait().await
    });

    // this delay should give tokio::spawn plenty of time to spin up
    // and call `wait` on the child (closing stdin)
    time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;

    // write character 24 (CANcel, ^X) to stdin to close nano
    stdin.write_u8(24).await.unwrap();

    match tasklet.await {
        Ok(exit_result) => match exit_result {
            Ok(exit_status) => eprintln!("exit_status: {}", exit_status),
            Err(terminate_error) => eprintln!("terminate_error: {}", terminate_error)
        }
        Err(join_error) => eprintln!("join_error: {}", join_error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I am seeing this behavior because I took (`Option::take`) `ChildStdin` out of `Child` and left `None` in its place?

Comment: Looking at the [source code for the exit method](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.0.1/src/tokio/process/mod.rs.html#924), I think this might be an issue in the documentation... I can't see anything in the code that closes `stdin`...

Comment: I asked about the above on [#tokio-dev](https://discord.com/channels/500028886025895936/500336346770964480/799034480597401600), my MRE should crash but there is indeed an issue in the code in that `wait` is not closing `stdin` in 1.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question is to `Option::take` `ChildStdin` out of `tokio::process::Child` as described in this [Github issue](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/3420). In this case, `wait` will not close `stdin` and the programmer is responsible for not causing deadlocks.

The MRE above doesn't fail for two reasons: (i) I took `ChildStdin` out of `tokio::process::Child` and (ii) even if I hadn't taken it out, it still would not have been closed due to a bug in the code that will be fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/pull/3421).